# Expectation of a norm

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

The matrix $\mathbf{N}$ has entries $[\mathbf{N}]_{i,j} \sim \mathcal{CN}(0,1)$ and the given vector $\mathbf{a}$ satisfies $\mathbf{a}^H \mathbf{a} = 1 $. 
I would like to calculate $\mathbb{E} \{|| \mathbf{Na}||^2 \}$ but I get stuck.
Do you have any idea or suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

If the entries of $\ \mathbf{N}\ $ are *independent*, then $\ \Bbb{E}\big(\mathbf{N}^H\mathbf{N}\big)=nI_{m\times m}\ $, where $\ n\ $ and $\ m\ $ are the numbers of rows and columns, respectively, of $\ \mathbf{N}\ $, and
\begin{align}
\Bbb{E}\left(\|\mathbf{Na}\|^2\right)&=\Bbb{E}\left(\mathbf{a}^H\mathbf{N}^H\mathbf{Na}\right)\\
&=\mathbf{a}^H\Bbb{E}\big(\mathbf{N}^H\mathbf{N}\big)\mathbf{a}\\
&=n\mathbf{a}^H\mathbf{a}\\
&=n\ .
\end{align}
If the entries of $\ \mathbf{N}\ $ are *not* independent, then you'd need to know the correlation coefficients, $\ \Bbb{E}\left(\overline{[\mathbf{N}]}_{ij}[\mathbf{N}]_{k\ell}\right)\ $, of all pairs of its entries to calculate $\ \Bbb{E}\left(\|\mathbf{Na}\|^2\right)\ ,$ and the condition $\ \mathbf{a}^H\mathbf{a}=1\ $ wouldn't be much help in calculating it (except in the special case where the correlation coefficients were all equal).

Answer (score 0):

Well $\|\mathbf{Na}\|^2 = \sum_i (\mathbf{Na})_i^2$ and $(\mathbf{N}a)_i = \sum_j \mathbf{N}_{ij} \mathbf{a}_j$. You can expand the square of $(\mathbf{Na})_i$ to get an expression for $\|\mathbf{Na}\|^2$ as a triple sum. Now interchange the expectation with the sums.

The last step is compute expectations of the form $\mathbb{E}(\mathbf{N}_{ij} \mathbf{N}_{ik})$ using your hypothesis on $\mathbf{N}$ (does $\mathbf{N} \sim \mathcal{CN}(0, 1)$ mean the entries of $\mathbf{N}$ are independent standard normal random variables?) and simplify using the hypothesis on $\mathbf{a}$ (does $\mathbf{a}^H$ denote the transpose of $\mathbf{a}$?).

Comment: I'd presume that $\ \mathbf{N}\sim\mathcal{CN}(0,1)\ $ means that $\ \mathbf{N}\ $ is [complex normal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_normal_distribution), and $\ \mathbf{a}^H\ $ is the *conjugate* transpose of $\ \mathbf{a}\ $.